# Why CountVectorsFeaturizer is used twice in config.yml produced by rasa init?

Tags: rasa-nlu

Below is part of config.yml generated by rasa init.

```
- name: WhitespaceTokenizer
- name: RegexFeaturizer
- name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
- name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
- name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  analyzer: char_wb
  min_ngram: 1
  max_ngram: 4
- name: DIETClassifier
```

It shows CountVectorsFeaturizer is being specified twice. Why is it so?

Comment: what version of rasa?

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, you simply take each token as a feature for the BoW, while 'char_wb' first creates character n-grams within the token's boundaries and then adds them to the BoW's feature set. The two pair well together. See doc [rasa](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components/#countvectorsfeaturizer) and [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).